# Select query with DateTime not working

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

It is my goal to query my table for records that exist between two dates and count the number of times a name is returned. If the value returned is more then three then I will print it to the screen.

For some reason it does not work for me.

Running PHP 5.3 with MySQL.

This is part of the code

```
<?php
$Today = @date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "Current Date: " . $Today . "<br>";

$FirstDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' -3 day');
echo "First date: " . (date('Y-m-d',$FirstDate)) . "<br>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytablename WHERE DateTime > '" . $FirstDate . "'");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows . "<br>";
```

The code continues from here to writing it to the screen. That part is working so I left it out.

The result with the above query simply returns all the records in the database and not only the records that are greater then the current date -3 days. Replacing the variable $FirstDate with '2014-12-12' does give the desired result.

Where is it going wrong? ORDER BY DateTime DESC seems to be sorting correctly so it does see it as a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define this in the SQL Command as well

```
SELECT * FROM mytablename WHERE DateTime > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Comment: Why dont add a variable between INTERVAL and DAY

Comment: This is working nicely. Thanks. Only got the records I am looking for now.

@IndraKumarS : If the 3 needed to be variable I would. But in this case it is a fixed value for something to report on. More then 3 means it needs attention.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `$FirstDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' -3 day');` it's converting it to a unix timestamp, not a date string. Try this:

```
$FirstDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` returns a unix timestamp not a Y-m-d string date which is probably what your looking for...

```
$FirstDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days'));
```